# Is it possible to use Rake to automate the build process for Android applications?

Tags: java, android, build-process, rake, build-automation

I'm looking into automating my Android application build process. I've been reading up mostly on whether to use Maven or Ant, but both seem to have big drawbacks. For my .NET work I use Rake and was wondering if it is possible to use Rake or something similar to build for Android development as well. There doesn't seem to be much information available online about this.

Is anybody using Rake to build android ? How has your experience been ? Do you recommend this instead of using Maven or Ant ?

Do you need any plugins to make this work ? Are there any available ?

Answer (score 3):

[Rhomobile](http://rhomobile.com/) uses rake for Android builds and other as well. But it's a cross-platform framework in which you use ruby. I believe [not many](https://github.com/jberkel/android-helloworld-rake/blob/master/Rakefile) use rake for Android. Did you try [gradle android plugin](https://github.com/jvoegele/gradle-android-plugin)? Here's more on [gradle](http://www.gradle.org/) itself.

Gradle is great because it's lighter than maven, still having it's power. It Handles your library dependencies and is easy to customize. Highly recommend.